# Entity Framework "detach without deletion" for filtering

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm having a problem with Entity Framework and filtering architecture.

Let's say that I have a couple of related entities, and I want to do some changes to them, based on a filter.

So, for example I have Orders and Orderlines (to put a simple example)
I have order1, with orderline1, orderline2, orderline3 relationships in the DB

Then I receive an update request for order1 but only for orderline1 and orderline3
I get the data from the db using entity framework, which retrieves an objectgraph of the order and its lines.

Is there a way to filter these entity objects so that I can work with an objectgraph that contains order1 and orderline1 and orderline3, but NOT orderline2 without that being a problem later?
Because if i remove orderline2 from the entitycollection, i get later on concurrency errors (or deleted entities, which is something i don't want)

I hope the question is clear, I know that there could be other ways (iterating and not performing updates on orderline2, so it remains the same and no changes are made) but the way the architecture was made doesn't let me do that right now.

If I could say "don't track any more changes to orderline2, just ignore any changes that I do to this particular object and descendants, just leave it in the DB the way it is", so that I can just remove it from the collection and move forward, that'd be perfect

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you deatch entity using Detach it won't be deleted...

Answer (score 0):

You can go multiple ways as you already described yourself as well:

1. Iterating through all orderlines and only modifying those that need to be modified (but that isn't an option as you stated)
2. The alternative you described to specifically not track changes for orderline2 is not possible in a "normal" EF situation where the ObjectStateManager is responsible for change tracking (as far as I know). In a scenario with Self Tracking Entities it's more easy because every STE has it's own unique ChangeTracker on board which can be easily switched off.
3. But the most easy option would be to exclude the orderlines you dont want to modify in the "select" statement or the retrieval of the entities. Something like:

---

```
private void ModifyOrderLines(int orderID, List<int> orderlineIds)
{
  using(Context context = new Context)
  {
    List<OrderLines> orderlines = 
    context.OrderLines.
    Where(orderLine => orderLine.OrderID == orderID && orderlineIDS.Contains(orderLine.ID))   
  } 
}
```

Assuming you have set up clean foreign key relationships which were translated into Navigation Properties in EF. So what you do is to get a list of OrderLines which belong to a certain order and have an ID that's in your list of OrderLines that need to be modified.

Afterwards you change the orderlines and apply the changes to the context and call SaveChanges. This is just a basic way of how you could do things. I don't know your exact setup but I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment I should just go for the easy way and write a loop as you already proposed. Why not? I don't think there are many alternatives, and if there are then they would make things overcomplicated.

So something like this might just work:

```
ObjectContext.OrderLines.ForEach(o => if(orderlineIds.Contains(o.ID) {o.SomeProperty = SomeValue}));
```

Or you could just write the loop yourself.

**EDIT2**

You already mentioned detaching from the ObjectContext in the title of your post. Why don't go that way then? You tell that you have no control over the ObjectContext that you get, that it is passed into several methods and that you get update requests for certain entities. Then detaching those entities that are not needed for the update request can be an option too. Maybe [this topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) might help you decide. Afterwards you might attach the detached objects again for they maybe needed for subsequent "client" calls. But this depends on how you manage the ObjectContext.

Do you keep the ObjectContext "alive" over multiple "client" calls or do you instantiate it over and over again for specific client calls. I do not get the situation totally clear...

Comment: Doesn't want to make a code block of the code I wrote. Anybody can do that?

Comment: the problem with the approach is that the methods are expecting the objectgraph, and here you're doing a query to just get the orderlines. i oversimplified the case, but imagine that we have the order with the orderlines and more things inside and inside, and we're updating properties here and there in all entities

Comment: hey! it's not that simple. the objectgraph goes into a couple of business logic methods that loop the collection and their related entities, checking properties in several places, doing changes in several places. yes, I could pass in a list of IDs to all the methods and do some manual filtering each time looping every collection, but that would mean doing a lot of refactoring, which is what i try to avoid, because the functionality already works